# Is the chunking option required with plupload and asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plupload

I have seen various posts where developers have opted for the chunking option to upload files, particularly large files.

It seems that if one uses the chunking option, the files are uploaded and progressively saved to disk, is this correct? if so it seems there needs to be a secondary operation to process the files.

If the config is set to allow large files, should plupload work without chunking up to the allowed file size for multiple files?

Comment: The reason I am asking is that I have tried it without chunking and having some io issues which I now suspect it not plupload related. Any confirmation of usage without chunking would be appreciated, will remove this question if it not a plupload issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that if one uses the chunking option, the files are uploaded
>   and progressively saved to disk, is this correct ?

If you mean "automatically saved to disk", as far as I know, it is not correct. Your MVC controller will have to handle as many requests as there are chunks, concatenate each chunk in a temp file, then rename the file after handling the last chunk.
It is handled this way in the upload.php example of plupload

> if so it seems there needs to be a secondary operation to process the
>   files.

I'm not sure I understand this (perhaps you weren't meaning "automatically saved to disk")

> If the config is set to allow large files, should plupload work
>   without chunking up to the allowed file size for multiple files ?

The answer is yes... and no.... It should work, then fail with some combination of browsers / plupload runtimes when size comes around 100 MB. People also seem to encounter problems to setup the config.

I handle small files (~15MB) and do not have to use chunking.
I would say that if you are to handle large files, chunking is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that one would need to implement the concatenation etc on the server. I guess this option is fine if one saves files to a folder, then processes those later (the secondary process) If really large files are being uploaded this also makes sense, but does'nt provide an elegant way of uploading files with additional metadata. I have gone for the non chucking option as I am purely just uploading files and don't want to introduce additional processed after upload. It still amazes me that a basic task such as uploads is not as definitive as it should be.

Comment: In fact, chunking does not really need any "additional process". Upon receiving a chunk, you directy concatenate its content to the content of the temp file, instead of saving it to a new file. You can even handle metadata, which is posted with each chunk (if I remember well)
You may have a look at the upload.php in plupload sources examples. It has enough comments to grab the idea of the process

Comment: ok, if thats the case, one can just process the file and metadata once the whole file is uploaded... which is fine. thanks...